# Desrialize JSON into List<List<KeyValuePair>> result is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I get a JSON result from an API

```
{"Data":[[{"Key":"Proudct","Value":"PC"},{"Key":"Address","Value":"USA"},{"Key":"Tel","Value":"123456777"}]]}
```

My Model Class:

```
public class MyData
{
   public List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> Data {get; set;}
   //public List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> Data {get; set;}
}
```

My Function

```
public async Task<MyData> GetDataAsync()
{ 
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("apiURL");

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(result);
       return data
    }

    return new MyData();
}
```

The result is always null unless I change KeyValuePair to Dictionary type. I cannot use Dictionary because "Key" will not be unique sometimes and I don't know why List<list> does not work as expected!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have `Result` as the property name but `Data` as the JSON key.

Comment: hint: in future questions please make sure to _completely_ include your JSON data. it seems like you're missing a surrounding pair of `{}`. additionally, try manually constructing an instance of your `List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>` and serialising it to JSON - to see if that _actually_ represents the structure of the data you're recieving

Comment: to follow up on the data structure: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jCpH6G

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: Create an object, set some values, serialize into text, and see what you get. Then you can figure out what does not match. Much faster than asking on stackoverflow. Or just use "Paste JSON as classes" in Visual Studio

Comment: @DainaHodges, there are a couple of things that could be happening here. Let's start here: Can you show us the exact value of `result` from this line: `string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`? I ask because the value you show at the top of your post is confusing to me.

Comment: Just curious... maybe it's a typo or copy-paste error. The name of your class is `Mydata` but you are trying to Deserialize to type of `MyData`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edits. I am not able to reproduce your issue. Take a look at this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/00vjcb

Comment: @CaseyCrookston your code works but I don't why it works with me only when I change the type to Dictionary

Comment: Yeah, I don't know either. This is why I questioned exactly what is the content of `result`. That's really the only variable I can think of. Maybe you could put a breakpoint, view `result` and show us the value?

Comment: Also make sure you are using NewtonSoft. System.Text.Json has weird failure modes, silent most of the times.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston 
"{\"Data\": [[{\"Käyttäjä\": \"Timo Kaisla\" },{\"Kustannuspaikka\": \"5150014\"},{\"Henkilö nro\": \"49417\"}]]}"

this gives me null

Comment: @DainaHodges Ok NOW I am able to reproduce your results. I will look into this more today and get back to you. (Are you still working on this?)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston yes.
And thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original post, you provided us with a sample JSON that looked like this:

```
{
    "Data": [[{
                "Key": "Proudct",
                "Value": "PC"
            }, {
                "Key": "Address",
                "Value": "USA"
            }, {
                "Key": "Tel",
                "Value": "123456777"
            }
        ]]
}
```

This works as you need it to! But when I asked you (in the comments) to provide the actual JSON coming back from the API, this is what you provided:

```
{
    "Data": [[{
                "Käyttäjä": "Timo Kaisla"
            }, {
                "Kustannuspaikka": "5150014"
            }, {
                "Henkilö nro": "49417"
            }
        ]]
}
```

This does not work. You can probably see why. The JSON you provided originally and the actual JSON are not the same. And now that I can see both sets of JSON, it makes perfect sense why the actual JSON can be serialized into a Dictionary but not a Key-Value Pair.

The code below gets you a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` from the JSON you are getting back from the API call:

```
public class MyData
{
    public List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> Data {get; set;}
}

static void Main()
{
    // Using your actual JSON from the api:
    string data = "{\"Data\": [[{\"Käyttäjä\": \"Timo Kaisla\" },{\"Kustannuspaikka\": \"5150014\"},{\"Henkilö nro\": \"49417\"}]]}";

    // Deserialize to MyData
    MyData myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(data);

    // Extract the inner List to a List<Dictionary>
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> dictionary = myData.Data[0];

    // Create our finished object
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyvaluepairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    // Loop over the List<Dictionary> and convert to List<KeyValuePair<>>
    foreach (var x in dictionary)
    {
        var key = x.ToList()[0].Key;
        var value = x.ToList()[0].Value;
        KeyValuePair<string, string> keyvaluepair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
        keyvaluepairs.Add(keyvaluepair);
    }            
}
```

By the time this code finishes, `keyvaluepairs` will have the `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` that you are looking for.

There is certainly a simpler way to do this (using LINQ) but this breaks it down so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an obvious solution, but have you considered using an online JSON to C Sharp Converter, such as https://app.quicktype.io.

I decided to give it a go, and got this, very simple class file.

```
namespace YourProjectName
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Temperatures
    {
        [JsonProperty("Data")]
        public List<List<Datum>> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Datum
    {
        [JsonProperty("Key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Temperatures
    {
        public static Temperatures FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temperatures>(json, YourProjectName.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Temperatures self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, YourProjectName.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Once you have this included in a file in your project, you can simply use it like this.

```
using YourProjectName;

var temperatures = Temperatures.FromJson(jsonString);
```

to make it more in line with your code.

```
public async Task<MyData> GetDataAsync()
{ 
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("apiURL");

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = Temperatures.FromJson(result );
       return data
    }

    return new MyData();
}
```